Automatic scrolling when the pointer reaches the edge of a window or page
I use the Logitech Trackman and love being able to scroll up or down with just a simple click of a button.

However, I would like to be able to scroll a page (usually webpage) when I reach the edge of a window, without having to click anything.
So far I have looked into apps that could simulate clicking the scrolling button of the mouse, and scroll apps such as Smart Scroll, Smooze, Auto Clickers etc, but I wonder if there is an easier way because nothing I've found has worked quite how I wanted.
I am using an older computer (running High Sierra), maybe Accessibility or Automator would allow me to do that but I haven't yet found out how.
Are there features of MacOS 10 that can be programmed to scroll on edge of pages, or easy ways to achieve this?

Are you referring to triggering a scrolling action when the cursor reaches the edge of a window?

Correct. It could be a window or a javascript window inside a website, too

That's a great idea. I'll consider implementing it in my macOS app.
